# Accessing specific elements in nested array

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, hash

I am trying to access this array of hashes:

```
[  
  {
    "Book": "1: SS",
    "Concordance": ". they tugged and heaved at the door, but it 
    wouldn’tbudge, not even when hermione tried her alohomora charm, now 
    what? said ron, these birds … they can’t be here just for decoration,",
    "Position": 82471,
    "Spell": "alohomora"
  },
  {
    "Book": "1: SS",
    "Concordance": "oh, move over, hermione snarled, she grabbed Harry’s 
    wand, tapped the lock, and whispered, alohomora! the lock clicked and 
    the door swung open — they piled through it, shut it quickly,",
    "Position": 47346,
    "Spell": "alohomora"
  },
  {
    "Book": "1: SS",
    "Concordance": "it on snape if he showed any sign of wanting to hurt 
    Harry, now, don’t forget, it’s locomotormortis, hermione muttered as 
     ron slipped his wand up his sleeve, i know, ron snapped, don’t",
    "Position": 65427,
    "Spell": "locomotormortis"
  },
]
```

How will I access the `Spell` within the second array element? How can I access a specific field of this array?

I have tried to do `Mentions.data[1]["Spell"]` but I know this is wrong.

Comment: Well, that's how you access any array usually.

Comment: "I know this is wrong" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* is wrong? *How* is it wrong? How do you know? What doesn't work? How doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 2):

Print `Mentions.data[1]` to see what Ruby sees.

```
{:Book => "1: SS",
 :Concordance => 
  "oh, move over, hermione snarled, she grabbed Harry’s \n" +
  "    wand, tapped the lock, and whispered, alohomora! the lock clicked and \n" +
  "    the door swung open — they piled through it, shut it quickly,",
 :Position => 47346,
 :Spell => "alohomora"}
```

Then it's clear to see we use:

```
Mentions.data[1][:Spell] #=> "alohomora"
```

Comment: Thank you! However irb is returning nil when entering the second code suggestion.

Comment: What does `Mentions.data[1]` return?